# How to extract data from facebook api or using php sdk for Job applications?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I did lots of research to find the proper guideline to get a few thing done but seems like really hard. All I am asking is below:

1. Anyone know in php how to extract posted jobs?
2. How to get job applications like all the users applied for job?
3. Where to start my code in php?

I know all below:

- business manager id
- app id
- app secret key from my created app.

but I don't know how to get the pageID?

I have also found this URL to get the job applications: [job applpications](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/jobs-xml/how-to#application-callback-payload)

but don't know how to perform from the above URL.

Please give me some guideline here as I am completely new to the Facebook API. Also, please if someone can provide me some starting point of php code to begin with my 1st and 2nd question.

[image]

Also if you check below image then it's showing that you can get applications from job:
[image]

Comment: what makes you think that it is possible to extract jobs from groups? did you find anything about that in the api reference?

Comment: please find the image under my question. Only because of information provided on FB I thought its possible to do so.

Comment: Also If you look at the second image I've placed in it's also showing that you can retrieve the job applications.

Comment: available on facebook.com does not mean available with the API.

Comment: so thr is no way I can retrieve applicant information:( I only found a way through ZAPIn but it's kind of manual to get the applicant out of job application table from facebook, Sadly I have to give up on this:(

Comment: scraping is not allowed on facebook, so there is no way, no.

Answer (score 0):

There is no publicly available Jobs API. Reading job posts via the /feed endpoint is also not supported.